# How to generate video thumbnail iOS without network call to server?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want is that when user pick the video from gallery i want to get the thumbnail image of the video.So is it possible to get the thumbnail image of the video without uploading it to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    __block NSData *movieData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:urlvideo];AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:urlvideo options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;


    CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);

    AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
        if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
            NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
        }

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:im];
    };
}
```